# Renaming a file results in 'No such file or directory'

Tags: php, filesystems, rename, file-permissions, file-rename

I've been trying to rename an image file using php using this code.

```
$user_id = $_POST[user_id];
$old_image_name = $_POST[old_image_name];
$image_name = $_POST[image_name];
rename('/_img/user_memes/large/user_'.$user_id.'/'.$old_image_name.'', '/_img/user_memes/large/user_'.$user_id.'/'.$old_image_name.'');
```

The error I'm getting is-

"Warning: rename(/_img/user_memes/large/user_2/1524957_717357634955838_1917151587_n.jpg,/_img/user_memes/large/user_2/1524957_717357634955838_1917151587_n.jpg) [function.rename]: No such file or directory in /var/sites/o/oddmeme.com/public_html/_process/post_single_meme_edit.php on line 8"

The image is definitely there. I've tried removing the / at the start and trying a few different version but nothing has worked.
I've also set permission to 777 so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have an error in your code:

You are using twice the same path in your function with $old_image_name...

Fix that and tell us if it's working.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response- Silly mistake ! 
I realised the script I was posting too was in a different folder and required me to go back a directory. ../ but I will take your advice onboard.

Comment: Yes it's working fine now - I had copied $old_image_name twice while testing different  techniques but I sorted that. Nothing worse than spending hours on a bit of code and realising it's a silly mistake like not going back a directory ha!

Comment: No problem, can you mark this answer as ok please ? =)

Comment: I can't vote up at the moment - as soon as my reputation is up I'll go back over old questions and vote people up. sorry buddy!